# device screen shots in android

Tags: android, webview, screenshot

i am using webview in layout,which contain a button ,on click of that button, i trying to capture device screen shot, on  click calling javascript method in my class, 
the

```
public void screenShots()
        {

         v1 = RelativeLayout.getRootView();
              v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);


        }
```

RelativeLayout is the layout which contain webview
when i run & clicks button to take screen shots,
it throws error

```
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'WebViewCoreThread'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.webkit.WebView.checkThread(WebView.java:9955)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.webkit.WebView.getSettings(WebView.java:4314)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.webkit.WebView.onDraw(WebView.java:4498)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11007)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11010)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2302)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:10724)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:10505)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:10470)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at com.curioussolutions.tashpatti.TashPatti$JavaScriptInterface.screenShots(TashPatti.java:90)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3900(WebViewCore.java:56)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1388)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 03:08:09.761: W/webview(21152):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:737)
```

what to do,is there any refrence to it

Comment: You can try this.

[Take screenshot][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file and store the image in SD card as like the following:

```
     // Declaration :

     private Activity activity;

     // Initialization :

     activity = MainActivity.this;


    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/.SomeWhereInSD", "photoToShare.png");
            saveImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            saveImage.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            saveImage.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    System.gc();
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(saveImage.getDrawingCache(true));
                    saveImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                    OutputStream outStream = null;


                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(photo.getAbsolutePath());
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                        outStream.flush();
                        outStream.close();

                        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError out) {

                    }
                };
            });
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using javaScript interface in your java code? Once I came across similar situation. javascript interface (in side a webViewClient) helped me.

I am using this as

```
private void openWebviewDialog(String days)
{
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.GLOBAL_CONTEXT);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.simple_webview);
    WebView wb = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.simple_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = wb.getSettings(); 
    wb.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.addJavascriptInterface(this, "javaScriptInterface");
    String url = "http://www.google.com" // your url here
    String title = "Hello";

    wb.loadUrl(url);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setTitle(title);
    dialog.show();
}

class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        if(url.contains("openExternal"))
        { 
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url); // Leave webview and use browser
        } 
        else 
        {
            view.loadUrl(url); // Stay within this webview and load url
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        Utils.hideSpinner();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) 
    {
        Utils.showSpinner();
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void passResult(String status, String message) 
{
   // Do as required. This method is called from JavaScript code of webView
}
```

This javaScriptInterface is called from webView as

```
<p>please wait while we are verifying your payment....</p><script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>javaScriptInterface.passResult('error','Your transaction failed');</script>
```

Comment: ya m using javaScript interface, but javascript interface (in side a webViewClient)????????????

Comment: I have just edited my answer, see if this helps you.